# Altium .CMPLib advantages over .SVNDBLib

Tags: altium, library

My team and I have been tasked with overhauling our library management system for components within our Altium Designer tool set. I am trying to understand the advantage (if any) of adopting the CMPLib paradigm over the SVNDBLib paradigm. We currently have most of our components in MSAccess databases or SQL databases in .DBLib format. As I understand it CMPLib allows for version control at the component level just as a SVNDBLib, however allows for a level of abstraction between a component and the associated Manufacturer Part Number and Supplier Part Number information. Can anyone elaborate on the advantage of this system over every component linking to a single MPN and SPN?